# Tengo un error con los permisos en tiempo de ejecucion

Tags: android-permissions

Hola amigos les comento que tengo un problema, tengo dos botones uno me permite tener acceso al micrófono y el otro guardar entonces necesito dos permisos, que me funcionan bien al ejecutar la app sale el letrero pidiendo los permisos y todo el problema es que no puedo usar los botones hasta que cierre y vuelva ejecutar la app les dejo la estructura espero me den un a orientación de que estoy haciendo mal.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1000);
    } else {                                    

      grabar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "La grabación comenzó", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });   
    guardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Se guardo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es la estructuración realizada. Al usar un "if(){} else{}" tal y como lo tienes planteado, si la condición para acceder al if es correcta, es decir no tienes permisos, ya no te entrará en el "else" ya que una excluye a la otra.
Como posible solución, puedes comprobar y conceder los permisos al comienzo de la actividad o bien directamente en el manifest, y por consiguiente definir las acciones de los botones.